# Issue with Backbone's hash style url without relative paths

Tags: ajax, hash, backbone.js, relative-path, deep-linking

I'm using Backbone to write my application. My application is setup so that I have a navigation ul on the left, and the main panel on the right. This means the user can navigate from one menu into its submenu and potentially more submenus.

Here's the problem. Because every page is identified by a hash, I'm now encountering fairly 'deep' links in my application (eg. #navigation/menu1/tab1, #navigation/menu1/tab2). This is very inconvenient as I traverse deeper into the page. Imagine putting links on hrefs that looks like #this/is/a/really/long/url/that/goes/on/forever. This is clearly a problem of ajax application's incapability in linking relatively like we're all used to in the conventional page by page style web applications.

I'm pretty sure I'm not alone. Wondering if anyone have a suitable solution for relatively linking your pages in your Backbone application (or really, any ajax applications)

Comment: It is all in how you design the app. You could just have all the tabs use unique ids and go with #tab1, #tab2, #tabn, etc.

Comment: @abraham, this is also a problem for untabbed applications.
Imagine viewing a catalog with the absolute link /catalog/1. Within the catalog, there may be a link to an individual product that takes you to /catalog/1/product/2/, in which you may click into a review that has link /catalog/1/product/2/review/3.

In a common page by page web application, the links you would put in your href's would be 'catalog/1', 'product/2', and 'review/3' respectively. However, in a purely ajax application, there are no relative links (they're all relative to root '/'), and you're force to use the absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem qite well, but here's how I like to design my hashes:

try using RESTful like urls/hashes instead of simply indicating the path. For instance, instead of "#menu/user/my-profile/edit-infos", prefer "#user/:id/edit" and use Backbone Routers to link your hashes to the correct views.